# How to use PowerShell to remove nonempty folder in OneDrive?

Tags: windows, powershell, onedrive

### Descriptions

Cannot remove nonempty folder in OneDrive directory

### Step to reproduce

1. Launch PowerShell in OneDrive directory

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive>
```

2. Try to use Remove-Item cmdlet to remove a nonempty folder in this directory, for example: the .\test\ folder

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive> Remove-Item .\test\
```

### Expected result

Without the -Recurse parameter, PowerShell should return a confirm message, such as

```
Confirm
The item at C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\test\ has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

### Actual result

PowerShell return a error message

```
Remove-Item: Cannot remove item C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\test\: The directory is not empty. : 'C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\test\'
```

### Note

1. PowerShell and Administrator:PowerShell get the same result;
2. If I exit OneDrive process and create a new nonempty folder under OneDrive directory, PowerShell can remove it as normal (see Note 4., because unsynced folders do not have the ReparsePoint attribute);
3. CMD can remove the folder successfully, which means I can use the below command in PowerShell to remove the folder too. But I want to accomplish my goal just by PowerShell cmdlet;

```
cmd.exe /C "rd /s test"
```

4. Get-ChildItem cmdlet shows that the mode of normal folders (not synced by OneDrive) is 'd'(directory), but the mode of synced folders is 'l'(reparsepoint). Is this the reason that I cannot remove a folder under OneDrive directory as normal?

### Version info

PSVersion：7.1.3

OS：Microsoft Windows 10.0.19042

OneDrive Version：21.052.0314.0001 (Office 365 A1)

### Update

I try to remove the test folder on PowerShell 5 but fail, too.

The error message from PowerShell 5.1:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive> Remove-Item .\test\ -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item : Access to the cloud file is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm .\test\ -Force -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Pretty sure file and folder objects are treated differently by `Remove-Item`. If I recall a script I wrote to do something similar I needed to remove the files first before removing the folders.

Comment: What happens if you try with `-Force` ?

Comment: Try `-Recurse`. You should look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: @Vivere I tried and it did not work. And normally, even if without `-Recurse` , PowerShell should return a confirm message (just like the expected result in question) instead of an error message.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried and it did not work. In fact, there is no hidden file or folder in the test folder, so I think `-Force` parameter is irrelevant.

Comment: @Scepticalist I know how to remove the chinditems first before removing the folder. I just want to know why unsynced nonempty folder can be removed by `Remove-Item -Recurse` easily, but the folders synced by OneDrive can't?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same thing and this worked for me:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse .\test | Sort-Object -Property FullName -Descending | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }
(Get-Item test).Delete()
```

I'm rather new at PowerShell, so there might be more elegant or correct ways to do the above.

Comment: It worked but doesn't delete the folders, only files.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer did not handle hidden files,
You can add these to your profile

```
function rmc ($file) {
    (Get-Item $file).Delete()
}


function rmd ($folder) {
    Get-ChildItem -recurse -force $folder | Sort-Object -Property FullName -Descending | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }
    (Get-Item $folder).Delete()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Onedrive folder's no different than any other folder in your system, the same folder removal PowerShell commands will be used. Here you go...

1. `cd` into the Onedrive folder.
2. Use, `rm -r -fo <FolderName>`

Answer (score 0):

If someone came here to just delete the folders with non-empty sub folders, I used the OneDrive app on Windows 10 to delete the folders and when OneDrive synced, the folder got delete from the cloud as well